# FragmentTabHost change tab name

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

After setting up my FragmentTabHost with addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(....)) I don't know ho to get the reference to the TabSpec.

All I need is to change the name of the tab (tabSpec.setIndicator("new name")) that I initially set with the mTabHost.newTabSpec method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer myself. Simply calling this method on the fragmentTabHost object works:

```
((TextView((RelativeLayout)getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabIndex)).getChildAt(textIndex)).setText("NewTabText");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more straight way to get the thing done:

```
((TextView) mTabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title))
.setText(yourTitle);
```

Whoever wrote this should have defined a `setTabText(int position, String text)` method, otherwise who would know they have a text view id'ed `android.R.id.title`? Or if they already had, please enlighten me.